# Ediff Changes Window Title

Tags: ediff

Before I launch ediff, emacs has this window title

```
0x08e000ac  0 spartacus scratch.spartacus.org - GNU Emacs at spartacus
```

, but after launch it has this

```
x08e01bc4  0 spartacus *Ediff Control Panel*
```

Any way to prevent this, as I use a keyboard combination to switch to emacs and I need the title of the window to stay intact for that to work.

```
    , ((modm .|. mod1Mask .|. controlMask, xK_e), spawn "wmctrl -a \"gnu emacs\"") -- extensible
```

Or any other way I can identify the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use this:

```el
(setq ediff-window-setup-function #'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

That will prevent a separate control frame from being created at all.

> Or any other way I can identify the window?

"Ediff Control Panel" seems reasonably unlikely to be used in the title for windows of other programs, no?